# Waiting on one Promise or another

Tags: javascript, selenium, protractor

I am testing a page that will sometimes render one widget, and sometimes another.

I am trying to use `browser.wait()` to ensure that ONE of the two has rendered, before going on to interact with the appropriate one depending on WHICH it is.

Here is my code:

```
EC = protractor.ExpectedConditions

browser.wait(() => {
      return EC.presenceOf(userField) || EC.presenceOf(notMyAccountElement)
}, WAIT_TIME, 'Lock form (auth0) never appeared.')

notMyAccountElement.isPresent().then((result) => {
  if (result) {
    notMyAccountElement.click()
    browser.wait(EC.presenceOf(userField), WAIT_TIME, 'New lock form (auth0) never appeared.')
  }
  userField.sendKeys(user)
  passField.sendKeys(password)
  submitBtn.click()
})
```

This usually works, but I get intermittent failures at:

```
userField.sendKeys(user)
```

I can see in the browser that occasionally this line executes when it is actually `notMyAccountElement` that is present on the page.

I think the most likely problem is that the opening `browser.wait()` is not resolving the way I am expecting it to, but I'd like to understand why.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you are not applying the expected conditions correctly, you need to use [`EC.or()`](http://www.protractortest.org/#/api?view=ProtractorExpectedConditions.prototype.or):

```
browser.wait(EC.or(EC.presenceOf(userField), EC.presenceOf(notMyAccountElement)), 
             WAIT_TIME, 'Lock form (auth0) never appeared.')
```

And, since you are interacting with `userField`, you should be probably using the `visibilityOf` or `elementToBeClickable` instead of `presenceOf` expected condition. Though, I doubt it is related to the intermittent failures.

You may also change the wait from waiting for presence/visibility of `userField` to invisibility/staleness of the `notMyAccountElement`. Replace:

```
browser.wait(EC.presenceOf(userField), WAIT_TIME, 'New lock form (auth0) never appeared.');
```

with:

```
browser.wait(EC.stalenessOf(notMyAccountElement), WAIT_TIME, 'New lock form (auth0) never appeared.');
```

Or, you may use both, one by one, to make things even more reliable.

Comment: Thanks @alecxe !  I'll try out `EC.or()` and post back if it solves my problems.

Comment: I have run using `EC.or()` for two straight hours without a single failure.  This seems to have done the trick.  Thanks again!